# Cascading IIR filter with All pass filter (APF) for constant group delay and linear phase over the passband using MATLAB not working?

Tags: lowpass-filter, infinite-impulse-response, linear-phase, group-delay, allpass

I've designed an IIR Low pass filter in MATLAB with the following parameters.

```
%IIR Filter Design
SamplingFrequency = 122e6; %Hz
PassbandFreq = 9.5e6; %Hz
StopbandFreq =10.5e6; %Hz
PassRipple = 1; %dB
StopbandRej=38; %dB
FilterIIR=designfilt('lowpassiir','StopbandFrequency',StopbandFreq, 'PassbandFrequency', PassbandFreq, 'SampleRate',SamplingFrequency,  'PassbandRipple',  PassRipple,'StopbandRej',DesignMethod="cheby2");`
[bi,ai]=tf(FilterIIR);

% All Pass Filter Design
 frange=(0:1:Fstop)/(Fs/2);   % do I need to multiply by pi?? for radian
gd=grpdelay(bi,ai,frange,2);
a=max(gd)-gd;
[bapf,aapf]=iirgrpdelay(6,frange,[frange(1) frange(end)],a);

% Cascading both system for linear phase and constant group delay

Num=conv(bi,bapf);
Den=conv(ai,aapf);
fvtool(Num,Den); % Visulalize the Cascade filter response
```

I have the following question:

- Am I doing any wrong in MATLAB code while defining the "frange"? (do I need to multiply by 'pi'). Note that: I tried to make the phase linear and group delay constant up to stopband frequency.
- Is it possible to design a low pass IIR filter within this given specification?

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: I hadn't used MATLAB to do this, but long ago (before I had MATLAB), I ***did*** cascade a Butterworth LPF with carefully tweaked a 2nd-order APF to get a more constant group delay in the LPF passband.  I dunno a good automated procedure, but maybe MATLAB's Signal Processing toolbox has one.  I did it by manually adjusting the $Q$ and $f_0$ of the APF until I matched the upslope of the bump in the group delay response of the Butterworth LPF to the downslope of the APF group delay.  It would have been more complicated if it were a higher-order APF.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson are you suggesting to use second order APF instead of single order and selecting butter-worth LPF might show constant group delay over the passband? My passband and stopband frequency distance is 1MHz and stopband rejection is 38dB just fyi. I will follow your suggestion. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, [it looks like this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jacek-Piskorowski/publication/227333697/figure/fig5/AS:668207073476616@1536324389833/Group-delay-of-the-phase-compensated-Butterworth-filter-and-the-original-Butterworth.png) when you do it right.  That transition bandwidth of 1/10 relative to the resonant frequency **does** determine the order of the Butterworth LPF you need.  The formulae are in the textbooks and other design books.  It's easy to figure out with Butterworth because of its simple and monotonic frequency response.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I am going to try this and will let you know if this works. Thank you very much.